# Using aws s3 sync with a date threshold?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do you use the awscli [`s3 sync`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) command to only sync files after a specific date?

I have a massive bucket with hundreds of GB of files spanning several years, but I only want to sync files for 2023 to my localhost.

The command has a `--query` parameter, so I tried using a filter like:

```
aws s3 sync <frombucket> . --query 'Contents[?LastModified>=2023-01-01][].{Key: Key}'
```

but that gives me the error:

```
Bad value for --query Contents[?LastModified>=2023-01-01][].{Key: Key}: invalid token: Parse error at column 24, token "2023" (NUMBER), for expression:
```

"Contents[?LastModified>=2023-01-01][].{Key: Key}"

What would the correct syntax be?

Comment: Do the objects have paths or keys that contain a date? eg `2023-01/invoices/foo.txt`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein No.

Answer (score 1):

From the doc:

> --query (string)
>
> A JMESPath query to use in filtering the *response* data."  This is consistent with all AWS CLI operations .

The underlying API call for listing S3 objects (eg for syncing) is https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects-v2.html.  As you can see, theres no LastModified filter for listing objects.

What you *can* do is put the date in the object paths as a prefix.  That's why it's best practice, if you want to conveniently filter S3 objects by date, to put their date in the prefix.